# Can you please explain this piece of code?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include CONST15
#define CONST2 CONST2*CONST1
#define CONST3 CONST2+CONST2
int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
printf("%\n",CONST3);
}
```

Comment: You appear to have missed the #'s among other things (like the first #include), or failed to note details about your compiler and build system that allow it being written like your post. Otherwise it just appears to use constants

Comment: Could you copy/paste the content of "styudio.h" file ? (Or at least verify this is not a type of "stdio.h" ?

Comment: Can you please first explain what is unclear about that piece of code?

Comment: you can see for yourself by generating a preprocessed file (for VC++, `/P` switch i believe, or it's available in the IDE .cpp file properties)

Comment: Another typo: `"%\n"` is probably not what you wanted for the format string... Also, `#include CONST15` is highly suspicious.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change `styudio` to `stdio`. The OP should correct me if that was not the intent. Also, we need to know what `#include CONST15` will pull in.

Comment: This seems more like a question about cpp, the c preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

First, preprocessing, which is the step that expands #defined'd symbols, happens before actual compilation.

Then, I don't think such a symbol can be recursive, but it can be replaced.  So if that is the full program, and assuming `<stido.h>` doesn't define a CONST15 or a CONST2, you won't get any reasonable results.  My compiler gives an error on the #include line that doesn't specify what to include.

However, you might compile it defining some symbols at compile time, such as:

```
gcc -DCONST15='"math.h"' -DCONST1=3 -DCONST2=5 foo.c
```

This would give the #include something (harmless) to work with, and provide a value for CONST1 and CONST2.

Then the first define would set CONST2 to 3*5 (just as that, not 15), and then the second define would set CONST3 to 3*5+3*5.